# Help re-open closed question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

This question was closed as "too localized": [Xcode expired certificate problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673113/xcode-expired-certificate-problem)

Someone is asking for a workaround for a known bug in Xcode that still hasn't been fixed more than 12 months later and it is affecting thousands of people (as far as I can tell).

The bug makes it impossible to compile your code, and the only official fix is a complete hard drive erase/operating system re-install every 12 months or so.

The accepted answer is basically saying "yes, it's a bug. wait for it to be fixed". There is also a comment with a link to a third party site with an actual workaround for the bug.

I really want to post the full answer incase that third party blog goes offline, but I can't because it has been closed as "too localized".

Based on the workaround, I suspect this bug occurs for *every single iOS developer* who doesn't do a full system re-install once a year. It is anything but "too localized".

Comment: I've re-open this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that the issue has been reported on March 2011, and the bug has not been yet fixed, I would not say the question is too localized. There is a workaround, and that makes the question perfectly acceptable. The fact the problem is present for any developer whose certificate is expired is another point to consider when considering the question too localized.

I guess that the fact the accepted (and only) answer essentially confirms it is a bug (and suggests to wait for the bug to be fixed) didn't help; add also that, in almost one year and a half, nobody has been able to write an answer with a workaround.

I can understand why the question has been closed: Knowing that the behavior I am noticing is a bug in the application I am using is not probably much helpful, if nobody can report a work-around for it. Now that the work-around is described in an answer, the question is more acceptable, IMO.

Comment: Understandable, but still wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it could make sense to close it based on the details in the question. But as someone who has wasted about $5,000 in contract-billable time trying to find a workaround for this bug, and finding many other people who have the same issue and don't know the answer... I feel it is worth upgrading a one line comment to a full answer.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert I agree. I am sure there are many developers for which that information is very useful.

Comment: Only problem is the workaround really isn't described in the answer. It's really just a link. If someone could edit and include the workaround in the actual answer, then I think there'd be a stronger case; however, at this time, I see a lot of link only answers, especially the two already deleted by the moderators.

Comment: @jmort253 The answer written by Abhi Beckert is not merely a link.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Okay, one out of four. :)  Takes a disciplined user to write a good answer on a NC, NARQ, Too Localized question. Not all are that disciplined, even some 10 and 20Kers.